# How to arrange data by unknow range of values

Tags: oracle11g

on the default schema HR I had the below  query that get count of employees at each department divided into ranges according to their salary category for example

1. group a with salary range in (5000 to 10000)
2. group b with salary range in (15000 to 20000)
3. group c with salary range in (+) .... etc

   SELECT
   CASE
   WHEN salary <= 5000 THEN  'A'
   WHEN salary >= 10000 THEN  'B'
   WHEN salary >= 15000 THEN  'C'
   ELSE  '+'
   END AS category ,
     COUNT(*) AS emp_count, department_id
   FROM employees
   GROUP BY
   CASE
   WHEN salary <= 5000 THEN  'A'
   WHEN salary >= 10000 THEN  'B'
   WHEN salary >= 15000 THEN  'C'
   ELSE  '+'
   END,  department_id
   ORDER BY department_id;
   /

but my problem is that the maximum and minimum salary are not known  or if the ranges are smaller then i had to write alot of codes to get the result 
so is their any other way that runs better than this one ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution for what I ask before but another question I found someone who used **Between** after the **select** part with **decode**  keywords to get the same result but without repeating the department row more than one...
the result will be 
I dont remember how he did it below what I remember

select salary between 1 and 1000 decode....

```
    Dept_name            Salary_Class          Employee_count       
   -----------          --------------        -----------------  
     Dept_name1             Class A                   3
     Dept_name2             Class B                   5
     Dept_name3             Class C                   1


SELECT b.department_name,
  CASE
WHEN a.salary <= 5000 THEN      'Class A'
WHEN a.salary >= 10000 THEN     'Class B'
WHEN a.salary <= 15000 THEN     'Class C'
WHEN a.salary >= 20000 THEN     'Class D'
WHEN a.salary <= 25000 THEN     'Class E'
END AS    salary_class,
  COUNT(a.employee_id) AS    employee_count
FROM hr.employees a, departments b
WHERE b.department_id = a.department_id
GROUP BY
CASE
WHEN a.salary <= 5000 THEN       'Class A'
WHEN a.salary >= 10000 THEN      'Class B'
WHEN a.salary <= 15000 THEN      'Class C'
WHEN a.salary >= 20000 THEN      'Class D'
WHEN a.salary <= 25000 THEN      'Class E'
END,
  department_name
ORDER BY department_name;
```